# Change the X-axis to month wise in R

Tags: r, graph

I am trying to plot my data in R, and I want to show the data monthwise. When plotted, the X-axis is breaked on yearly basis, though the data is for 3 years only, the X axis is broken as 2015, 2015.5, 2016 and so on. How to change the X axis plot to reflect it as Jan 2015, Mar2015, May 2015... and so on.

Data

Time Period   Actual call volume

8/1/2015    69676

9/1/2015    71827

10/1/2015   62504

11/1/2015   59431

12/1/2015   63304

1/1/2016    58899

2/1/2016    55922

3/1/2016    60463

4/1/2016    56121

5/1/2016    58574

6/1/2016    64467

7/1/2016    61825

8/1/2016    75784

9/1/2016    67047

10/1/2016   63000

11/1/2016   63318

12/1/2016   66612

1/1/2017    71614

2/1/2017    62875

3/1/2017    66297

4/1/2017    66193

5/1/2017    70143

6/1/2017    72259

7/1/2017    65793

8/1/2017    53687

9/1/2017    48518

10/1/2017   58740

11/1/2017   50801

12/1/2017   44293

1/1/2018    61150

2/1/2018    49619

3/1/2018    49621

4/1/2018    48645

5/1/2018    37958

6/1/2018    37725

7/1/2018    42221

8/1/2018    41663

9/1/2018    35328

10/1/2018   37687

11/1/2018   31657

12/1/2018   26390

1/1/2019    27542

2/1/2019    23262

Comment: What was your code for the plot?

Comment: If you're not going to give us any data you may as well try http://earlh.com/blog/2009/07/07/plotting-with-custom-x-axis-labels-in-r-part-5-in-a-series/ good luck.

Comment: Data as requested.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should obey the comments from above.
It seems that you are new to stackoverflow and it may help you to have something to play with to get started .

I like to plot those things with *ggplot* and ggplot requires a dataframe for plotting.

```
date <- as.Date(c('8/1/2015', '9/1/2015', '10/1/2015',
              '11/1/2015', '12/1/2015', '1/1/2016'),
            format = "%m/%d/%Y")

value <- c('69676', '71827', '62504',
           '59431', '63304', '58899')
df <- data.frame(date, value)
```

In ggplot you can use the dataframe *df*, define some aesthetics *aes* which help creating the axis and can then define in a very comfortable way the format of the axis text.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(date, value))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")
```

[image]

@user1945827 pointed you to something to read, if you want to use base plots. As my favorite plotting library is **ggplot** I want to reference [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) and [this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html)

Comment: @Saagar, if you accept the answer, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).